# Can you use variables with NG-CLASS active link with Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ng-class

I want to use a loop to create my navigation Here is my code I keep getting an error saying it won't evaluate as a string? The code that I wrote is so that it will loop through the $scope.navigation and use that to write out the navigation so I don't have to write out each list and anchor tag?

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html ng-app="Sample">
    <head>
       <title>Sample Angular App</title>
       <script src="Scripts/basket.js"></script>
       <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/global.css"/>
       <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
       <script src="controllers/main.js"></script>
       <script src="routes/route.js"></script>
  </head>
   <body>
     <div class="navigation" ng-controller="AppCtrl">
         <ul class="cf" >
            <li class="link {{link.name}}" ng-class="{{link.name + 'Active'}}" ng-repeat="link in navigation">
              <a href="{{link.route}}" ng-click="setActive($index)">{{link.name |      uppercase}}</a> 
            </li>
        </ul>
     </div>
     <div class="wrapper">
       <div ng-view>

       </div>
     </div>
   </body>
  </html>
```

My main js script file looks like this:

```
          function AppCtrl($scope) {

            $scope.navigation = [

                { name:"main", route:"#/"},
                { name:"edit", route:"#/edit" },
                { name: "save", route: "#/save" },
                { name: "settings", route: "#/settings" }

            ];

            $scope.currentPage = null;

            $scope.setCurrentPage = function (index) {

                $scope.currentPage = $scope.navigation[index];

            }

            $scope.setActive = function (index) {

                angular.forEach($scope.navigation, function (value, key) {

                   $scope[value.name + 'Active'] = "";

                });

             var active = $scope.navigation[index].name;

                $scope[active + 'Active'] = "active";


            }

        }
```

It keeps giving me an error saying that the {{link.name}} cannot be evaluated as a string but it is a string? Is there a way to loop through a $scope.navigation and get it to output the navigation without having to manually write it out and still add the setActive function? I am kind of new at working with angularjs. Is there a way to fix this issue or is it that doing things this way is not allowed in angular?

Comment: Where is link defined in your scope?

Comment: Nevermind, I found it scrolling sidewise on the code

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's a much better/easier way to accomplish setting a `active` CSS class. Just save a single value in your scope that holds the value of what is active. Something like this:

```
$scope.setActive = function (index) {    
  $scope.activeIndex = index;
};
```

Then `ng-class` allows you to give it an map where "the names of the properties whose values are truthy will be added as css classes to the element" (From http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngClass).

So you can set the CSS class if the `$index` is the `activeIndex`:

```
ng-class="{active: $index == activeIndex}"
```

Comment: I don't understand it completely but it worked thank you so much for your help, I really like Angular js I am going to keep working with it. I really appreciate you taking the time to answer my question. I just learned Angular this week.

Comment: Please mark as as answered if this solution did in fact work for you.

Comment: I have another question please? I am having difficulty sending it to my module, I scoped everything properly the controller is reading the scope but I can't access the setActive() function? is there a nested scope issue? I wanted to separate the click function from the ng-click and use it in the controller so when the page loads the active link is already highlighted.

Comment: If you want the active class applied on page load, you just need to set activeIndex to whatever index should be highlighted in the controller. Before anything calls `setActive()`, `$scope.activeIndex` is undefined. So, if you just put something like `$scope.activeIndex = 0;` in the controller, it will start at 0 and the first one will be highlighted.

Answer (score 2):

I've tested the dnc253's solution. But it doesn't seems worked anymore.

I had to create a method like this:

```js
$scope.isActive = function(index){
    return $scope.activeIndex === index;
};
```

And in html :

```html
ng-class="{active: isActive($index)}"
```

This works fine.